# Resolve missing methods for the new log4j dependency

Tags: java, maven, log4j

I have been using the old version of log4j imports which we used to customize the log4j getLogger as:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
    ...
public static Logger getLogger(Class<?> className) {
    Properties log4jProperties = new Properties();
    try {
        log4jProperties.load(new FileInputStream(LOG_PROP_FILE_LOCATION));
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jProperties);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
        System.out
                .println("FileNotFoundException while fetching the properties file from the specified location: "
                        + LOG_PROP_FILE_LOCATION);
        fileNotFoundException.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        System.out
                .println("IOException while fetching the properties file from the specified location: "
                        + LOG_PROP_FILE_LOCATION);
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Logger.getLogger(className);
}
```

But now for the new version of log4j 2.17.1, looks like PropertyConfigurator and getLogger are completely changed. Not finding an resolution to fix it. Have tried the below. But it doesn't work.

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationSource;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationBuilder;
...
public static Logger getLogger(Class<?> className) {
    Properties log4jProperties = new Properties();
    try {
        log4jProperties.load(new FileInputStream(LOG_PROP_FILE_LOCATION));
        //PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jProperties);
        LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext)LogManager.getContext(false);
        Configuration config = new PropertiesConfigurationBuilder()
        .setConfigurationSource(ConfigurationSource.NULL_SOURCE)
        .setRootProperties(log4jProperties)
        .setLoggerContext(context)
        .build();
        context.setConfiguration(config);
        Configurator.initialize(config);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
        System.out
                .println("FileNotFoundException while fetching the properties file from the specified location: "
                        + LOG_PROP_FILE_LOCATION);
        fileNotFoundException.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        System.out
                .println("IOException while fetching the properties file from the specified location: "
                        + LOG_PROP_FILE_LOCATION);
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Logger.getLogger(className);
}
```

Can someone shed some light on how to resolve this?

**UPDATE**:
This is the error which I receive when trying my fix:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContext cannot be cast to org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext
    at com.ds.mdm.details.batch.util.BatchLogger.getLogger(BatchLogger.java:74) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.ds.mdm.details.batch.DetailsJobLauncher.<clinit>(DetailsJobLauncher.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

Comment: _"But it doesn't work"_: what are the symptoms? Are you aware that Log4j 1.x and Log4j 2.x properties configuration files have a different format? To parse (a basic version) of the 1.x format use the [`PropertiesConfigurationFactory`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-1.2-api/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/config/PropertiesConfigurationFactory.html) from `log4j-1.2-api` (beware the package name, the 2.x format factory has the same class name).

Comment: Yes @Piotr. I receive the error as provided in the UPDATE. Throwing cannot cast exception.

Comment: It seems you have [`log4j-to-slf4j`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.2/log4j-to-slf4j/index.html) on your classpath, which sends all messages submitted using the Log4j 2.x API to SLF4J. Remove it.

Comment: It is not in my classpath. And so, I have added exclusions in my pom.xml as "<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>". But still the jar is getting downloaded in the maven dependencies.